# how can i add datatable features to this table

Tags: html, jquery, json, codeigniter

datatable features are missing after adding data dynamically to the table

```
    $table = "";
    $table.="<table class='datatables-demo table table-striped table-bordered' id='advance_loan_outstanding'>
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Employee ID</th>
                            <th>Company</th>
                            <th>Employee Name</th>
                            <th>Amount</th>
                            <th>Advance Date</th>
                            <th>Monthly Deduction</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                      <tbody>";

        foreach($employee->result() as $row){

            $company = $this->Xin_model->read_company_info($row->company_id);
            if(!is_null($company)){
                $comp_name = $company[0]->name;
            } else {
                $comp_name = '--';  
            }
            //fullname
            $full_name = $row->first_name.' '.$row->last_name;  

            $get_advance_loan_employee = $this->Reports_model->get_advance_loan_employee($row->employee_id, $row->advance_or_loan_count_helper_id, $row->table_name);
            


            $table.="<tr>
                        <td>".$row->employee_id.".</td>
                        <td>".$comp_name."</td>
                        <td colspan='4'>".$full_name."</td>
                    </tr>";

            foreach($get_advance_loan_employee as $r){

            $table.= "<tr>  
                        <td colspan='3'></td>
                        <td>".$row->Amount."</td>
                        <td>".$r->month_year."</td>
                        <td>".$r->monthly_installment."</td>
                        
                    </tr>";
            } }
        $table.="</tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Employee ID</th>
                            <th>Company</th>
                            <th>Employee Name</th>
                            <th>Amount</th>
                            <th>Advance Date</th>
                            <th>Monthly Deduction</th>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>";

        //print_r($employee);exit();
      echo json_encode($table);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hNls.png)

Comment: you need to add datatable js and CSS file then on dom load initialize datatable using jquery.

Comment: If you're adding HTML/rows to the [tag:datatables] *after* it's been initialised, then you need to either re-initialise or use the datatables API to add data.  Don't add directly to the HTML and expect datatables to magically know what you've done.

Comment: i have added all datatable api files in external folder and loaded it links.. thats not the problem.rest of my datatable in this system is working properly.but its not working